# SQL: not a single group function .... not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, aggregate-functions, min

I have a number of tables detailing a shop's customers and sales, etc.

I want to find the minimum sale price; i.e. a single result returned by the SQL expression.

In order for the result to make sense I also want to join the customer_sale table with the customer table (so that the customer in question will also have his/her name returned).

Using the following code

```
SELECT CUST_ORDER.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.FNAME, CUSTOMER.LNAME, MIN(SALE_PRICE)
FROM CUST_ORDER
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER
ON CUST_ORDER.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER.CUST_ID
GROUP BY CUST_ORDER.CUST_ID
HAVING MIN(SALE_PRICE) = (SELECT MIN(SALE_PRICE) FROM CUST_ORDER GROUP BY CUST_ID)
```

in Oracle 11g throws the following error:

> ERROR at line 1:  ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Which makes sense as it is only to return a single result.

However deleting the GROUP BY clauses causes the dbms to throw the following error:

```
SELECT CUST_ORDER.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.FNAME, CUSTOMER.LNAME, MIN(SALE_PRICE)
FROM CUST_ORDER
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER
ON CUST_ORDER.CUST_ID=CUSTOMER.CUST_ID
HAVING MIN(SALE_PRICE) = (SELECT MIN(SALE_PRICE) FROM CUST_ORDER)
```

> ERROR at line 1:  ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Is there some additional nesting that I have to do for the statement to execute correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really just getting the min for an entire table, perhaps just this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUST_ORDER.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.FNAME, CUSTOMER.LNAME, SALE_PRICE
FROM CUST_ORDER
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER
ON CUST_ORDER.CUST_ID=CUSTOMER.CUST_ID
WHERE SALE_PRICE = (SELECT MIN(SALE_PRICE) FROM CUST_ORDER)
```

I'm not sure if you need `DISTINCT` or not, or how your data looks.

Comment: Seems to work spot on!

Answer (score 1):

In your first query, it seems that you need to additionally GROUP BY the customer's first name and last name since you are also choosing to SELECT them:

```
SELECT CUST_ORDER.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.FNAME, CUSTOMER.LNAME, MIN(SALE_PRICE)
FROM CUST_ORDER
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER
ON CUST_ORDER.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER.CUST_ID
GROUP BY CUST_ORDER.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.FNAME, CUSTOMER.LNAME
HAVING MIN(SALE_PRICE) = (SELECT MIN(SALE_PRICE) FROM CUST_ORDER)
```

Comment: Thanks but that generates this error "ERROR at line 6: 
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row"  :P

Comment: I see...  you would need to remove the group by from the SELECT MIN(SALE_PRICE) FROM CUST_ORDER GROUP BY CUST_ID.  I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: This latest version looks like it may work...always good for the OP to have choices!